# How to set the background image of a panel from a resource file in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to change the background image of a panel in a C# [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application. The image I want to set as the background is located in a resource folder in [Solution Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Other_tools). How do I use it in code?

I tried this:

```
panel1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Chalkboard;
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: hey mark the answer of joshua as solve this answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tried the same code like you did, and it works fine when I hit a button.

```
private void pnlBgBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.image;
}
```

The name 'image' in 'Properties.Resources.image' should be the name you gave to the image.
The right name of the image should be the name shown in your project properties under project-proje.

Answer (score 2):

The properties.Resources class doesn't return every resourse as an image so you have to apply a cast to Image like this

```
panel1.BackgroundImage = (Image)(Properties.Resourses.Chalkboard);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should not say in a answer "Vote up if this helps" and Code must be formatted with Markdown. In this case, add four spaces before the word panel1 to format it properly.

Comment: @Zanon ... Got it. Tnx

Answer (score 1):

You can try this out:

```
 Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().
    GetManifestResourceStream("MyProject.Resources.myimage.png"));

 panel1.BackgroundImage = bmp;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the background image of a panel on page load then you have to write this code:

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    Assembly asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    Bitmap backgroundImage = new Bitmap(asm.GetManifestResourceStream("Image913.jpg"));

    e.Graphics.DrawImage(
        backgroundImage, 
        this.ClientRectangle,
        new Rectangle(0, 0, backgroundImage.Width, backgroundImage.Height),
        GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
}
```

If you want set the image except the panel, load use this code:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().
GetManifestResourceStream("MyProject.Resources.photo0018.jpg.png"));

panel1.BackgroundImage = bmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an icon resource in Properties project folder. When you opened Properties click on Resources.resx and there Add Resource->Add New Icon menu items. This will create an icon. You can also load an icon from an existing file into the resource, in this case the icon will be built in your executable. So, when your icon added as a resource it will be given some name.